# How to convert this json into C# object

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I am receiving this JSON from third party hence have no control over it,

```
{
    code: 200,
    message: success,
    data: {
        categories: {
            0: {
                prop1: 100,
                prop2: blah
            },
            1: {
                prop1: 100,
                prop2: blah
            }
                    // etc.. etc.. it may return around 100 or more categories or less
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to convert it to C# object,

```
[DataContract]
public class Category
{
    [DataMember] public string prop1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string prop2 { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Data
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Category> categories { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public int code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string message { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

and code to convert it,

```
   var response = LoadPageAsync(url).Result;
   var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   var rootObject = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(response);
```

Problem is I am getting Categories count coming as zero even though there are many in JSON it self.

Comment: Is there any reason in particular you're using JavascriptSerializer and not Json.NET?

Comment: @Bejasc I am new to serialization but I am open to any better solution :)

Comment: NewtonSoft.Json is pretty much the de-facto standard of serialization in C#.

Comment: Obviously you´re using the [DataContractJSONSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data) instead of a `JavascriptSerializer`.

Comment: The categories in the json is not an array, it's just two objects "0" and "1" but the deserializer expects a list in your code

Comment: @ahrberg you are right that's what the main problem is... and I don't have much control on JSON :(

Comment: @Mathematics just use one of the examples below. But I guess you still have problems if the strings is not in quotes. You also needs to solve that before deserialize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your list of categories to a dictionary. Tested the following code and I achieved deserialization as needed. It's also worth noting that your json is actually *invalid* without the quotes surrounding the strings. I also used JSON.Net, but that should be irrelevant.

```
[DataContract]
public class Category
{
    [DataMember] public string prop1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string prop2 { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Data
{
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<int, Category> categories { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public int code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string message { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var root = new RootObject()
    {
        code = 1,
        message = "test",
        data = new Data()
        {
            categories = new Dictionary<int, Category>()
            {
                { 0, new Category()
                    {
                        prop1 = "cat1prop1",
                        prop2 = "cat1prop2"
                    }
                },
                { 1,  new Category()
                    {
                        prop1 = "cat2prop1",
                        prop2 = "cat2prop2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    var testJson = "{code: 200,message: \"success\",data: {categories: {0: {prop1: 100,prop2: \"blah\"},1: {prop1: 100,prop2: \"blah\"}}}}";
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
    var testConvert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(testJson);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Deserializing a Json to an object becomes as easy as:

```
string json = @"{
  'Email': 'james@example.com',
  'Active': true,
  'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
  'Roles': [
    'User',
    'Admin'
  ]
}";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
// james@example.com
```

As their own [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) show.

Json.NET will convert any Json to an object, as long as you have it defined in your code. `Account` in this case can be anything, `RootObject` in your case. Also it will probably return some useful exceptions, if something with your Json doesn't fit the standard.

Comment: Really? this is the answer?

Comment: @r41n my JSON is different then yours, I can't do it this way

Comment: @Mathematics, the Json doesn't matter, Json.NET will convert any Json to an object, as long as you have it defined in your code. `Account` in this case can be anything, `RootObject` in your case.

Comment: The Json shown here is taken from Json.NET sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid `json`, strings need to be enclosed in `"`.

You can test your `json` here:

https://jsonlint.com/

This is valid:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "success",
    "data": {
        "categories": {
            "0": {
                "prop1": 100,
                "prop2": "blah"
            },
            "1": {
                "prop1": 100,
                "prop2": "blah"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Zero
    {

        [JsonProperty("prop1")]
        public int Prop1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("prop2")]
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class One
    {

        [JsonProperty("prop1")]
        public int Prop1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("prop2")]
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Categories
    {

        [JsonProperty("0")]
        public Zero Zero { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("1")]
        public One One { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {

        [JsonProperty("categories")]
        public Categories Categories { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {

        [JsonProperty("code")]
        public int Code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Data Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Using Newtonsoft Json:

```
var example = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(json);
```

Comment: Please re-read the question. It states that it is from a third party source and there is no control over the json format.

Comment: @Bejasc the json is invalid as-is, so it's impossible to deserialize unless it's made valid..short of writing your own deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

here you can find many method to do what you want, i personally like JavaScriptJsonSerializer.
[enter link description here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/json-serialization-and-deserialization-in-c-sharp/)

Using JavaScriptJsonSerializer

JavaScriptSerializer is a class which helps to serialize and deserialize JSON. It is present in namespace System.Web.Script.Serialization which is available in assembly System.Web.Extensions.dll. To serialize a .Net object to JSON string use Serialize method. It's possible to deserialize JSON string to .Net object using Deserialize or DeserializeObject methods. Let's see how to implement serialization and deserialization using JavaScriptSerializer.

Following code snippet is to declare custom class of BlogSites type.

```
class BlogSites  
{  
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public string Description { get; set; }  
}
```

**Serialization**

In Serialization, it converts a custom .Net object to a JSON string. In the following code, it creates an instance of BlogSiteclass and assigns some values to its properties. Then we create an instance of JavaScriptSerializer and call Serialize() method by passing object(BlogSites). It returns JSON data in string format.

```
// Creating BlogSites object  
BlogSites bsObj = new BlogSites()  
{  
   Name = "C-sharpcorner",  
   Description = "Share Knowledge"  
};  



// Serializing object to json data  
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
string jsonData = js.Serialize(bsObj); // {"Name":"C-sharpcorner","Description":"Share Knowledge"}
```

**Deserialization**

In Deserialization, it does the opposite of Serialization which means it converts JSON string to custom .Net object. In the following code, it creates JavaScriptSerializer instance and calls Deserialize() by passing JSON data. It returns custom object (BlogSites) from JSON data.

```
// Deserializing json data to object  
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
BlogSites blogObject = js.Deserialize<BlogSites>(jsonData);  
string name = blogObject.Name;  
string description = blogObject.Description;




// Other way to whithout help of BlogSites class  
dynamic blogObject = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonData);  
string name = blogObject["Name"];  
string description = blogObject["Description"];
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17374888)

Comment: @derape thank you for your advice. i did so in my edit

Answer (score 0):

Using Json.NET

```
public class Category
{
    public string prop1;
    public string prop2;
}

public class Data
{
    public List<Category> categories;
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int code;
    public string message;
    public Data data;
}
```

Remove the `DataContract` code to make a simple class structure.

Deserialize the object using JSON.Net

```
RootObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

RootObject being your top level object.

You should then be able to access it like any normal object, ie

`string firstProp1 = RootObject.data.categories[0].prop1`

Comment: This will fail to deserialize because categories is not a simple array, but rather an object containing more objects.

Comment: @StephenVernyi you can still access the index in the list as if it were an array.

edit: sorry I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: But Newtonsoft will throw an error because it can't deserialize properly.

Comment: misunderstood your original comment, apologies.

Comment: All good. Json's finicky and subtle changes require entirely different class structures. It's annoying at times